# MVC 5 Seed user to aspNetUserRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to initially seed my db with a user, some roles and then want to try to have a user assigned to that role. I can currently seed users and roles without an issue but i come a cropper when trying to add the user to the role.

Here is what i have

```
 //Create the role 
        if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Admin"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" };

            manager.Create(role);

        }

        //Create a new user
        if (!(context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "admin")))
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            var userToInsert = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin", Email = "admin@admin.com" };

            userManager.Create(userToInsert, "Password@123");
            //Assign the user to the role. 
            //This is where i'm having the problem!
            userManager.AddToRolesAsync(userToInsert.Id, "admin");

        }
        if (!(context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "worker")))
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            var userToInsert = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "worker", Email = "worker@worker.com" };
            userManager.Create(userToInsert, "Password@123");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use magic strings. Move role outside of If scope, and when adding user to roles, use role.Name. That way, you won't have the problem you currently have, which is your role is "Admin" but you're adding to "admin".

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method that requires an array. I think you probably want:

```
userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userToInsert.Id, "Admin");
```

or

```
userManager.AddToRolesAsync(userToInsert.Id, "Admin".ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with `async` method. To overcome this problem you could write one of the following codes:

1. Use `AddToRole` extension method instead:

   ```
   userManager.AddToRole(userToInsert.Id, "Admin");
   ```
2. Call `Wait()` after calling `AddToRoleAsync`:

   ```
   userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userToInsert.Id, "Admin").Wait();
   ```
3. Or use `async`/`await` pattern:

   ```
   public async Task Foo()
   {
       // other codes

       await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userToInsert.Id, "Admin");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i could do it this way

```
 var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        if(!context.Users.Any(t => t.UserName == "markabarmi@hotmail.com"))
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "markabarmi@hotmail.com", Email = "markabarmi@hotmail.com" };
            userManager.Create(user, "passw0d!");

            context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name, new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
            context.SaveChanges();
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
        }
```

which nicely works for me
Thanks for the comments